# Excel: How to apply more than one funtion?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file which I basically want to manipulate existing data from column A and output the result to column B.

So column A contains:  Foo BAR foo bar:bar
I need column B to output: foo-bar-foo-bar-bar

The formula must lower the case and remove all spaces and non alpha characters.

I have the following formula applied which generates a lowercase version but I can't figure out the rest.

=LOWER([@[content_title]])

Any ideas? Is it even possible to apply multiple functions within a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can apply multiple functions.
You can use something like that:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","-"),":","-"))
```

Unfortunately you must use a SUBSTITUTE function for all character what you want to replace with "-", or you can use VBA function for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to chain functions in excel. All you need to do now is nest Substitute and you should be good!

=SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", "-")

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Sam Marion. However, I bow have this which doesn't work...

=LOWER([@[content_title]])+SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","-")

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry this should work =LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32),"-"))